# Добавление класса при клике другому блоку div

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день, подскажите как добавить класс при клике на

```
<div class="block-menu-link"><span>TEXT 1</span></div>
```

другому блоку `<div class="lefel-block">` добавлялся класс, а второму и последующим нет:

```
<div class="block-menu-big">
  <div class="left-block">
    <div class="block-menu-link"><span>TEXT 1</span></div>
    <div class="block-menu-link"><span>TEXT 2</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="block-menu-link">
    <!--меню TEXT 1-->
    <div class="lefel-block">
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.1.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.3.1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--меню TEXT 2 -->
    <div class="lefel-block hidden">
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Наишите, при клике на `TEXT 1` какому блоку должен добавиться класс. Только при клике на `TEXT 1` должен добавляться класс?

Answer (score 3):

Можете сделать так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block-menu-link').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('simple_left_block');
    console.log($(this).parent().attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-menu-big">
  <div class="left-block">
    <div class="block-menu-link"><span>TEXT 1</span></div>
    <div class="block-menu-link"><span>TEXT 2</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="block-menu-link">
    <!--меню TEXT 1-->
    <div class="lefel-block">
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.1.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.3.1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--меню TEXT 2 -->
    <div class="lefel-block hidden">
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

При клике на ваш блок добавить класс его родителю, если класса его нет, а если класс есть удалить. Логику добавления можете менять как хотите.

А если нужно при клике добавить класс всем блокам с классом `lefel-block`, то сделайте так:

```
$('.block-menu-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.lefel-block').toggleClass('simple_left_block');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

вот на чистом  vanila.js

```js
const texts = document.querySelectorAll(".block-menu-link"); // выбираем все .block-menu-link
const lefelBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".lefel-block"); //выбираем все .lefel-block
texts.forEach((text) => { // перебираем все .block-menu-link
  text.onclick = () => { //  назначаем каждому из .block-menu-link
    lefelBlock.forEach((item)=>{ // перебираем все .lefel-block
      item.classList.add('newClass'); // назначаем у .lefel-block новый класс
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.newClass{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-menu-big">
  <div class="left-block">
    <div class="block-menu-link"><span>TEXT 1</span></div>
    <div class="block-menu-link"><span>TEXT 2</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="block-menu-link">
    <!--меню TEXT 1-->
    <div class="lefel-block">
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.1.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 1.3.1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--меню TEXT 2 -->
    <div class="lefel-block hidden">
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mmenu-colums">
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.1</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.2</a>
            <a class="link seo-menu__link" href="">TEXT 2.3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Во, за чистый JS респект.